# Kubernetes database operator that automatically creates credentials

Tags: database, kubernetes, operators, kubernetes-helm

I got a task, to create a helm-chart and use a kubernetes database operator that creates automatically credentials for the database.

I don't really understand how is this possible.
I found this operator in Operator hub: https://operatorhub.io/operator/postgresql-operator-dev4devs-com

This is an operator for postgreSQL. It is mentioned that :

- Allow you setup the operator to get the values required for its enviroment variables (user, password and database name) in an ConfigMap applied in the cluster already. *NOTE: It is very useful to centralize and share this information accross the cluster for your solutions. Also, you are able to configure each configMap keys that contains each EnvVar* required for the PostgreSQL database image.

If someone has experience with kubernetes operators, could I get a hint, which one should I use? (easiest, it doesn't have to be Postgres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not much fan of operators not writing unless required or keeping it as the last option.

To understand it easily consider it like there are different types of operator

- Helm-based operator
- Ansible operator
- Go, python other language-based operators

Which use the framework to [Operator framework](https://github.com/operator-framework)

You have to create one Helm-based Operator which keep watch on a secret if removed or does not exist it will create the new one for the Database.

Steps :

1. Install the Operator SDK first
2. `operator-sdk new db-operator --api-version=harsh.com/v1alpha1 --kind=DbSecret --type=helm --helm-chart=db-secret --helm-chart-repo=<repo url>`
3. Add/Edit the helm chart YAML with DB secret creation as you are planning
4. Consider **kind:DbSecret** as values.yaml in helm
5. Build and deploy the Operator (operator-sdk build) it will watch for configmap/secret if not there it will create it

you might have to create the necessary service account, role, and role binding.

Ref document to create the helm operator : https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/helm/tutorial/

Comment: I couldn't find anything about ```kind:DbSecret```. Forgive me, I am a complete beginner with k8s and helm.

Comment: When you will create operator using above Shared link you will be able to create kind:Dbsecret or any name you want to keep. Follow the link in answer you will get idea. It’s easy and straight forward don’t worry.